# Bot is not able to join session in bot emulator

Tags: c#, botframework

I have recently updated my windows to windows 10 and visual studio 2019, after that whenever i try to run my bot on Bot Framework Emulator , my bot is not able to join in the session. Earlier i was working on windows 7 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2017. All the nuget packages are installed and updated to latest versions.

I debugged my Bot Controller class , in which on attaching breakpoint over `PostAsync()`'s method request , response , i got following errors :

```
Length  '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse)Response).Body).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}
Position    '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse)Response).Body).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'   long {System.NotSupportedException}

ReadTimeout '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.WriteOnlyStream)((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse)Response).Body).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' int {System.NotSupportedException}

WriteTimeout    '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse)Response).Body.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    int {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

I am having a dispatch model bot working on both LUIS & QnA maker, I have not changed anything in my code , it was working fine earlier in previous windows version. My system is also not in any restricted network, I have checked that too, Proxy is also disabled.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors on your console in VS 2019? Also, which version of the emulator are you using? Can you make use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to debug your bot locally?

Comment: i solved this issue, ngrok was getting blocked from my work network

Answer (score 0):

This issue which caused by ngrok side has been solved , summary OP's comment so that it will help others who has the similar issue :

> Ngrok was getting blocked from my work network